# Как заставить выполнять скрипты toLoad?

Tags: jquery

Использую код для подгрузки контента:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

     $('a').click(function(){

     var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #contant-main';
     $('#contant-main').hide('fast',loadContent);
     $('#load').remove();
     $('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
     $('#load').fadeIn('normal');
     function loadContent() {
     $('#contant-main').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
     }
     function showNewContent() {
     $('#contant-main').show('normal',hideLoader());
     }
     function hideLoader() {
     $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
     }
     return false;

     });
    });
```

Все идеально отрабатывает, но есть одно НО. Скрипты что имеются в подгруженных страницах не выполняются, javascript, ajax, jquery вообще ничего. Какие изменения требуется внести в код чтобы скрипты работали?